# React native image picker is not selecting video from library in iOS 13 or higher

Tags: iphone, reactjs, react-native, ios13, react-native-image-picker

React native image picker with version 0.28.0, react native 0.59.5 and iOS version less than 13
was working fine.
But after upgrade to iOS 13+, it does't select videos from library and returns permission error in response.How to achieve specific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in apple's latest iOS update 13 or 13+, it clearly states **Privacy and Security update** but does't disclose any documentation at spot.
Earlier react-native-image-picker used to move item from local directories while selecting a video from library. But this update restricted to copy item from local directory instead of moving.

I **fixed it** by changing **moveItemAtURL to copyItemAtURL** at **line 459** on ImagePickerManager.m

Open **project>node_modules>react-native-image-picker>iOS>ImagePickerManager.m**

Comment: @Abdul_Basit is it working for all versions of IOS?

Comment: Yes @niveshshastri

Comment: Unfortunately this fix didn't work for me.